# using variable to static method in nodejs and typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

i have a class and this class i need to use the static method and in that method i use the varibale but it show me this errror :

> Property 'ec' does not exist on type 'typeof Wallet'.ts

and i not need to set static that variable .

how can i sovle this problem ?

```
export class Wallet {

    ec: any;


    constructor() {
        this.EC = elliptic.ec;
        this.ec = new this.EC('secp256k1');
    }


    static verifySignuture(address: string, data: any, signature: any): boolean {
        const keyfromPublic = this.ec.keyFromPublic(address, 'hex');
        return keyfromPublic.verify(Utility.GenerateHash(data), signature);
    }

}
```

**how can solve this prblem ?**

Comment: Why didnt you set static, static is necessary to make that function static (ie. accessible from the type).

Comment: You state "need to use the static method"... Why does it need to be static?  If it needs to be static, then `ec` must be static too.  It's clear that you do not understand what `static` means, and need to read about *classes*, *class members* and *static class members*.

Comment: You can't use non-static members in static methods. Non-static members are bound to the class instance, static method are called on a class without an instance. Which `this` should the static method reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript class != an instance of this class.

Imagine class as some shape defined by a fields inside it. You instantiate this shape by using a `new` keyword. In javascript (typescript as well) you can assign your class' instance to a variable. For example

```
const myWallet = new Wallet();
```

and then you can have another instance assigned to yet another variable

```
const someOtherWallet = new Wallet();
```

In this case `myWallet` and `someOtherWallet` has the same `shape`, but there are two separated instances of the same shape (class). By using `static` word, you are assigning field of your shape to shape itself instead of constructed instance. So if your method is static, instead of calling `this.myMethod()` you need to call `MyClass.myMethod()` - in your case `Wallet.verifySignature()`. The difference is about the `this` word. It represents a javascript context within you are operating in specific part of the code. [You can find more about it here](https://towardsdatascience.com/javascript-context-this-keyword-9a78a19d5786). Advantage of a `non-static` methods of a class is being able to access `this` context within those methods. If you do not need to access `this` you can go ahead and use static method. In first case (when I assigned new instance of a class `Wallet` to a local variable named `myVallet`, `this context` (inside a `Wallet` class) is equivalent to a variable named `myVallet`, but the difference is from where you are gonna access it. In your case you are trying to access `this` context inside a `verifySignature` method, which is wrong, because inside static method of a class, `this` context is not an instance of your class. Instead remove a `static` keyword before method declaration and try something like this:

```
const wallet = new Wallet();
const signatureVerified = wallet.verifySignature(address, data, signature);
```